# React conditional rendering bug even with single parent and child list

Tags: reactjs

Learning a bit of React but it seems to me like there's a conditional rendering bug with React itself.

Suppose I have a `Foo` component like so:

### foo.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Foo extends Component {
  render() {
    const isLoggedIn = this.props.isLoggedIn;

    return(
      <div>
        { isLoggedIn ? (
          <div>one</div><div>two</div>
        ) : (
          <div>one</div><div>two</div><div>three</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Foo;
```

and I use it like so:

### app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Foo from './components/foo';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Foo isLoggedIn={false} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This produces the error:

```
Syntax error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag
```

Please note the above Foo component, there is only a single parent div being returned not array. If it was an array, then yes I agree with the error.

The official example given in the React document's example is like this:

```
render() {
  const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
  return (
    <div>
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />
      ) : (
        <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Does this look like a bug in React to anyone?

### Update

Based on the answers and comments given here, the implied behaviour of React is ternary operators inside the `render()` function comes with it's own `render` calls behind the scenes, acting like a virtual component, which would mean an extra layer of `<div>` needs to be wrapped around the list of my child elements.

### Emberjs Foo component

My confusion arise from the fact I have done some Emberjs development in the past and a component like this works as expected:

```
<h3>Foo component</h3>

{{#if isLoggedIn}}
  <div>one</div><div>two</div>
{{else}}
  <div>one</div><div>two</div><div>three</div>
{{/if}}
```

Thanks for the explanation from everyone nonetheless.

Comment: I am not returning a list of element Shubham, I am returning a single parent div node with child elements inside, which according to React's doc is perfectly fine.

Comment: I guess you are returnign multiple elements, may not be from render but in the conditional render  here `<div>one</div><div>two</div>`

Comment: I come from a different background but I did not know a ternary operator in React is treated as another "virtual component" with it's own render call behind the scenes.

Comment: yes they are treated as separate block of JSX elements. I marked it as a duplicate considering the Other question solved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the 2 or 3 divs in the condition. Instead you should wrap them into on div and return.

Notice the **wrapper** div below.

```
{ isLoggedIn ? (
      <div className='wrapper'><div>one</div><div>two</div><div>
    ) : (
      </div className='wrapper'><div>one</div><div>two</div><div>three</div></div>
    )}
```

Also note that there is small typo below

```
<div>one</div><div>two</div><div>three</div
```

Comment: This does seem to fix the issue if I wrap another layer of div inside multiple elements but what I want to know why it's necessary?

Comment: One simple rule in React. Wherever you are returning, always return on element, not multiple elements. In your example you are returning 2 divs on true conditions and 3 divs in false condition.

Comment: @Zhang, I hope this explaination helps. :)

Comment: So just one of those ins-and-outs of React that isn't documented somewhere but learnt from the hard way?

Comment: I cannot comment on the complete react documentation as I haven't read each and every line of it :) . But whatever I have read, the quality is very good and I am pretty sure that this is mentioned somewhere in documentation (may be indirectly).

Comment: And I think the error message is very direct and simple to understand. May be some debugging can be handy. :)

Comment: I understand what the error means just the other hidden knowledge and understanding about React is what got me. Thank you for the answer nonetheless.

Comment: Happy to help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error

```
          <div>one</div><div>two</div><div>three</div
```

should be

```
          <div>one</div><div>two</div><div>three</div>
```

Comment: Sorry typo, but the error still appears after fixing the typo.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding  ?

```
return(
      <div>
        { isLoggedIn ? (
          <Fragment><div>one</div><div>two</div><Fragment>
        ) : (
          <Fragment><div>one</div><div>two</div><div>three</div><Fragment>
        )}
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: Fragment also work like ivp's answer of wrapping extra `<div>` around the list of elements but real question is why this is necessary ?

Comment: Just a note: Fragment is also a right answer. However, the concept of Fragments was not present in earlier release. Hence will not work with code using older react version.

Answer (score 1):

> **Syntax error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag?**

you are returning multiple sibling JSX elements in an incorrect manner.

In Foo:

```
return(
      <div>
        { isLoggedIn ? (
          <div>one</div> //are siblings without 
          <div>two</div> //wrapping in container element.
        ) : (
          <div>one</div> //are siblings without 
          <div>two</div> //wrapping in 
          <div>three</div>//container element.
        )}
      </div>
    );
```

Right approach :

```
return (
            <div>
                {isLoggedIn
                    ? (
                        <div> //add wrapper
                             /...
                        </div>
                    )
                    : (
                        <div> //add wrapper
                            //...
                        </div>
                    )}
            </div>
        );
```

Or

If you are using React16 then you can use [`React.Fragement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) as well:

e.g.

```
<React.Fragment>
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
</React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the element rendered in the condition

```
return(
  <div>
    { isLoggedIn ? (
      <div><div>one</div><div>two</div></div>
    ) : (
      <div><div>one</div><div>two</div><div>three</div></div>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

Note the extra `div` around the nested conditional elements